# raw_input, dictionaries, and classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In Python 2.7, I'm trying to make it so when the user inputs a name, it searches to see if that name is in the predefined dictionary, and then if it is, it creates an object using a class and using the dictionary's values. Here's my code so far:

```
import os

weaponList = {
'axe': {'Name': 'axe', 'Mass': 1500, 'Strike': 'Chop'},
'knife': {'Name': 'knife', 'Mass': 300, 'Strike': 'Cut'},
'club': {'Name': 'club', 'Mass': 2000, 'Strike': 'Blunt'},
'stone': {'Name': 'stone', 'Mass': 800, 'Strike': 'Blunt'},
}

class meleeWeapon:
    def __init__(self, name, mass, strike):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = mass
        self.strike = strike

def weaponask():
    wepn = raw_input("Use knife, club, axe, or stone?\n> ").lower()
    if wepn in weaponList:
        currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(wepn['Name'], wepn['Mass'], wepn['Strike'])
        print "success"
    else:
        print "item not recognized"
        weaponask()
    #return wep

weaponask()

os.system('pause')
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
Use knife, club, axe, thrown stone, slung stone, or firearm?
> axe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\dict.py", line 30, in <module>
    weaponask()
  File "C:\Python\dict.py", line 23, in weaponask
    currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(wepn['Name'], wepn['Mass'], wepn['Strike'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str


Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? TIA

Comment: Try to change `wepn['Name']` to `weponList['Name']`?

Comment: `weaponList` is a poor name for a structure that isn't a list. Also, you can put `meleeWeapon` instances straight into the dictionary, instead of the subdictionaries of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wepn` is a string that the user has entered. In your case could be `"knife", "club", "axe" or "stone"`. You need to use `weaponList` instead.

For example, `weaponList["Knife"]` would give you `{'Name': 'knife', 'Mass': 300, 'Strike': 'Cut'}`.

Replace this:

```
currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(wepn['Name'], wepn['Mass'], wepn['Strike'])
```

with this:

```
currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(weaponList[wepn]['Name'], weaponList[wepn]['Mass'], weaponList[wepn]['Strike'])
```

**UPDATE**

You could do as jonrsharpe suggested in the comments (looks cleaner too!)

```
currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(**weaponList[wepn])
```

Comment: Alternatively, unpack the dictionary straight into the class `currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(**weaponList[wepn])`, or just store `meleeWeapon` instances in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

change your currentWeapon to :

```
currentWeapon = meleeWeapon(weaponList[wepn]['Name'],weaponList[wepn]['Mass'],weaponList[wepn]['Strike'])
```

becouse wepn is key of weaponList and for accessing to data of wepn so first you should access wepn (weaponList[wepn]).